# AJAX returning both query result and string?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, string, pagination

I'm trying to create an ajax search function, where user is to enter the search criteria, then ajax grab those data and send them to php to query the result from the database, then it returns the result along with the pagination link stored in a string.

In the javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.song_filter').change(function(){
      var url = 'listing/ctrl';
      var data {
            title:   $('#title').val();
            author:  $('author').val();
      }

      $.post(url, data)
      .success(result) {
          var jsonObj = $.parseJSON( result );
          output_list(jsonObj); /* fetch out the result */
      }

  });

});
```

And in my php listing/ctrl, I have both the query result and the paginated link ready to return. I have no problem returning only the query result on its own, but I don't know how to return both the result and the link.

```
$result = $this->pagination->get_result();
$page_nav = $this->pagination->page_nav(); // <li class="page">2</li><li class="page">3</li>

echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: You could always append the link to the JSON and then parse for it properly when you receive it.

Comment: in the php side? json_encode ($result, $page_nav)?

Comment: Yes, in the PHP side.

Comment: can you elaborate more?

Comment: Take the output of $page_nav and make it suitable to be placed in a JSON string, like an array element. Concatenate it to $result and then json_encode the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append the link to the json object, something like this:

```
$result = $this->pagination->get_result();
$page_nav = $this->pagination->page_nav();

// create an object to store the result and the link
$json = new stdClass();
$json->link = $page_nav;
$json->data = $result;

echo json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

And the in your ajax success

```
.success(result) {
      var jsonObj = $.parseJSON( result );
      jsonObj[0].link /* Here comes the link */
      jsonObj[0].data;
  }
```

Comment: this is more organized than mine trying array_push the link to the $result array, thanks. And in jsonObj, it should be without the '[0]'